# Update application cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to make my site work offline and I did it. But the problem is that I can't update my manifest file. I have the function that should check for update and update it if is possible but I don't know why it's not working.

This is my `index.html`

```
<html manifest="VideoPlayer.appcache" >
<head>
    <title>Video Player</title>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body id='main'>

    ...

    <script>

        window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
            window.applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', function(e) {
                if (window.applicationCache.status == window.applicationCache.UPDATEREADY) {
                    window.applicationCache.swapCache();
                    if (confirm('A new version of this site is available. Load it?')) {
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                } else {}
            }, false);
        }, false);

    ....

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my VideoPlayer.appcache:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

index.html
style.css
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
```

Can You tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: If the data in the manifest (e.g. the *html file name(!!!)) doesn't change, there will be no change event as far as I know (haven't worked with it myself though) Maybe a good read: http://alistapart.com/article/application-cache-is-a-douchebag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether your Javascript can make it easier (I sure hope so!), but what I have learned from experiments with appcached files is that they are only successfully updated/refreshed/reloaded in Chrome and Firefox under the following conditions:

- The in your case `VideoPlayer.appcache` file itself must also be updated. You can do that by including a date and time in the file and change that to the date and time that you update the web page. See the below code block how to include date and time.
- Chrome's normal but total browser cache must be cleared as well; just doing a 'hard reload' with Ctrl + F5 won't do. See here how to clear it: http://www.guidingtech.com/1662/clearing-cache-in-google-chrome/.
- In Firefox, that doesn't even do, not even in combination with Ctrl + F5. Firefox's *Offline Cache* must be cleared: `Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Network -> Offline Web Content and User Data -> Remove [site]`.

Here is the date and time method for the appcache file:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2014-06-25 — 15.50

CACHE:
[your to-appcache files here]
```

Changing the date and/or time will tell the browser that the to-appcache file is updated and should be reloaded.

I have not tested matters in IE, among others things because I don't have IE10, and IE9 doesn't do appcaches.

Let me know how it works out if you will, especially in combination with your Javascript.